# How to Open VSCode from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, terminal, vscode-remote

How to Open Visual Studio Code Using PowerShell? What should I write on PowerShell?
I wrote (code) and (code .) doesn't open.

```
PS C:\Users\ahmed> code.
code. : The term 'code.' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ code.
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (code.:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Try to open VSCode by PowerShell.

Comment: the location of the executable file needs to be in your PATH environment variable. Or, otherwise, provide the full path to the executable.

Comment: For example, see the instructions here: https://techpp.com/2021/08/26/set-path-variable-in-windows-guide/ In my case, code is located at `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe`, so I would add `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code` to my PATH (probably just to my user environment variables - but it will probably work either at the "user" or "system" level, as discussed in the linked instructions above).

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Fix (add to PATH)

1. Open Visual Studio Code and open the command palette (ctrl+shift+p OR cmd+shift+p) and start typing `Shell command`
2. You will then see a command that reads: **SHELL COMMAND:INSTALL CODE TO PATH** -> SELECT/CLICK THIS COMMAND
3. A success window will pop up, now your issues should be solved!!!! Now in the terminal (after restarting it) try to code . or any vsc command and watch it work! (if the issue persists see the steps below)

### Issue Explained

If vscode is installed and working properly otherwise, the issue is it needs to be added to your PATH so you can execute the commands globally from Powershell, cmd, etc. So running the vsc command to add to your path will immediately fix this issue.

**DISCLOSURE** Sometimes it is possible to still have issues after (such as when you restart your machine..this means the PATH is not being saved). If this is your case then here are some steps to troubleshoot(double-check) and add to the path manually and indefinitely:

### 1.  Check the Installation Path:

To check if Visual Studio Code is in your system's PATH, you can use the following PowerShell command:

#### Display the directories in the current PATH

```
$env:PATH -split ';'
```

Look for the directory where Visual Studio Code is installed. If you don't see it, you'll need to add it.

### 2. Add VS Code to PATH:

To add Visual Studio Code to the system PATH, you can use the following PowerShell commands:

#### Get the current PATH variable

```
$currentPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

#### Path to the directory where Visual Studio Code is installed

```
$vsCodePath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code"
```

#### Add Visual Studio Code to the PATH if it's not already there

```
if ($currentPath -notlike "*$vsCodePath*") {
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', "$currentPath;$vsCodePath", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
    Write-Host "Visual Studio Code added to PATH. Please restart PowerShell."
} else {
    Write-Host "Visual Studio Code is already in the PATH."
}
```

Replace the $vsCodePath variable with the actual path where Visual Studio Code is installed on your system.

After running these commands, you may need to restart your PowerShell session to apply the changes.

### 3.Open Visual Studio Code:

Now, you should be able to open Visual Studio Code using the code command.